# Collection name as predicate (ie. as an xpath filter of some sort)?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a collection `/db/apps/myfoo/data` (in eXist-db 4.7) where `/data` contains a few hundred collections like so:

```
/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0001
/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0002
/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0003
/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0004
/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0005
etc.
```

Each collection contains a large number of XML documents each with an attribute `@corresp` like `@corresp="TC0001"`.

In my Xquery modules I load the data collection into a variable

```
let $mydata := collection("/db/apps/myfoo/data")
```

because this entire `data` collection will be accessed in many different ways by the functions.

At one point I need to count the documents inside each collection, so I will add a predicate like:

```
let $ct := count($mydata//tei:TEI[@corresp eq "TC0001"])
```

But I'd like to speed up the counts (if possible) by adding the collection as a predicate instead of forcing a search across thousands of unrelated 
documents. As I understand it, a collection isn't exactly a `node`. So is this possible?

Here is an example in pseudo-code where `TC0001` would be the collection:

```
let $ct := count($mydata/TC0001/tei:TEI)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about collections in database systems but can't you just do `count(collection("/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0001")/tei:TEI)`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes, I do that as an alternative, but I was hoping to use the `$mydata` already loaded into memory....assuming that was faster if I have to cycle through and count the contents of 200 collections?

Comment: It depends on the particular implementation and its options I think whether `collection` caches any result and returns a cached instance I think, not sure how that works in a database. Does `head($mydata//tei:TEI[@corresp eq "TC0001"]) is head(collection('/db/apps/myfoo/data/TC0001')[1])` give true or false?

Comment: It returns `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a node you can get the URI of the document using `fn:document-uri(fn:root($node))`.

From that you can get the Collection URI using a little regular expression like `fn:replace($doc-uri, "(.*)/.*", "$1")`

You can then use that in a predicate comparison.

For example:

```
let $mydata := collection("/db/apps/myfoo/data")
let $ct := count($mydata//tei:TEI[fn:replace(fn:document-uri(fn:root(.)), "(.*)/.*", "$1")  eq "my-sub-collection-name"])
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that can be applied to the particular problem above with any extra efficiency? ie. applying it as predicate to `$mydata`...

Comment: I assumed from your question that your data collection had many sub-collections and you wanted to filter some of them in/out. If not I don't understand your question

Comment: Right, I just don't see how to apply your response to my context! I know already the names of subcollections, so the question is whether that can be used as a predicate/filter on a main collection already in an existing a variable.

Comment: @jbrehr I added an example, which I hope solves your problem